# Synchronizing ListView Selected Item property value with what is displayed

Tags: listview, binding, windows-runtime, selection, winrt-xaml

I set the `SelectedItem` property in a `ListView` using a `TwoWay` binding to an item of the displayed list in my WinRT App. I know that the binding works correctly because the same binding is used somewhere else on the page.

However, when the `ListView` is first displayed, it doesn't show any item as `Selected`.

Once I click on one of the `ListView` items, the selections go well and the binding works well (I see that through the other control that is bound on the selection variable.)

So my question:
**How to make sure that `ListView` shows the `SelectedItem` as selected when first showing up?**

I tried using the `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` property, but setting it to `true` causes an (useless) exception at runtime, and VS2012 tells me that "setting this property to `true` is not supported."

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue i solved with the SelectedIndex property.

I had set both SelectedItem and SelectedIndex.

```
myListView.SelectedIndex = indexOfInitialSelectedItem;
myListView.SelectedItem = itemThatShouldBeSelected;
```

You can get the index of the item when you use the IndexOf() method of you ItemsList oder Enumerable like this:

```
myItems.IndexOf(itemThatShouldBeSelected);
```

Maybe this works out for you too.

Comment: Ok, so no way to achieve this through XAML-only code then? I'll give a try. I tried setting the SelectedIndex by hand in XAML before, but as far as I remember it crashed (or at least didn't work, can't remember).